# Advanced Segments returning unexpected results in Google Mobile App Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm having a problem with *Advanced segments* in Google Mobile App Analytics.

A condition has been setup to include all screens that match regex "/01-12-2013/" - but it's also showing me screens which does not contain this string. For example I'm getting a screen name containing "/11-11-2013/" which I would have expected to be filtered out.

The segment seems to return different results based on which tab I'm in in Google Mobile App Analytics. If that helps at all.

In "Audience Overview" I's returning 48.02% of all Screen Views. In "Behavior Overview" it's returning 71.51% of all screen views.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem.

[image: Advanced Segment]

[image: Audience Overview]

[image: Behavior Overview]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? User retention and/or return usage analysis based on their install cohort?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound a bit ridiculous but, when creating advanced segments, after you've created them, I'd give them an hour or two before relying on the data they provide.  I still have yet to find a solid answer as to why this is, but across a wide range of sites over the past year or two I've found similar issues.  I've noticed that when I create an advanced segment to filter specific pages, invariably the initial results still show irrelevant pages I specifically filtered out.  The only thing I've been able to attribute this to is some sort of "lag", on Google's side, in updating the Analytics data/property/view/segment.  In almost every case, I've simply waited an hour or two after creating an advanced segment, and the data that was filtered usually displays correctly by then.

An interesting thing I've also seen was that a third party reporting platform I use, that has a Google Analytics integration, actually displayed the correct advanced segmented data BEFORE it showed up properly in Analytics.  Strange.